# Observable not pulling data with AsyncPipe

Tags: angular, observable

I have my `AccountService` defined as follows:

```
 export class AccountService {
    user: Observable<PlatformUser>;
    isAdmin: boolean;

    constructor(private http: Http) {
        this.getUser();
    }

    private getUser() {
        if (this.user) { return this.user; }
        else {
            this.user = this.http.get("account/userinfo")
                .map(result => {
                    let user: PlatformUser = result.json();
                    user.isAdmin = user.roles.indexOf("InformationTechnology") != -1;
                    this.isAdmin = user.isAdmin;
                    return user;
                });
        }
    }
```

And I'm referencing it from one of my components.

```
export class HomeComponent implements OnInit {
    user: Observable<PlatformUser>;

    constructor(private accountService: AccountService) {
    }

    ngOnInit() {
        this.user = this.accountService.user;
    }
}
```

Inside my view, just as a test... i'm not able to pull out the data I'm expecting. If I subscribe to the event and assign the result to a variable, everything works fine, but I want to use AsyncPipe to avoid manually having to set that up.

```
{{user | json}}
{{user?.firstName | async}}
```

The first one is for my debugging purposes... it shows me that I'm not pulling back all the data I should be. All it shows is the following:

```
{ "_isScalar": false, "source": { "_isScalar": false }, "operator": {} }
```

The second one doesn't show anything. I'm missing a key bit of knowledge here that's holding me back, and looking for enlightenment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if `user` is getting back to you as an observable and you can subscribe to it, you can try to something like this `{{ ( user | async )?.firstName }}`

first you need to pass the `user` observable through the `async` pipe. 
When there is data available from it, you can call the `user.firstName` like it's a regular variable.

Comment: That works! Can you elaborate a little on why it is necessary, in your answer?

Comment: Thank you so much. This is great. I didn't even think of this because I've used Observables with async pipe before that didn't have to do this. I guess because they were already populated with data.